# Error calculation of a 5-dimensional vector

Tags: python, math

I am trying to calculate the error percentage of a 5 variable vector and for this I compare the magnitudes of the obtained vectors with the correct vectors and calculate the average error. In this code, which I first made by considering random values, an error of 8.5% was found. I'm asking for confirmation, is this operation mathematically correct?

```
def accuracy_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    i=0
    difs=0
    while i<len(y_true):
        difs=abs(np.linalg.norm(y_true[i])-np.linalg.norm(y_pred[i]))\
                /(np.linalg.norm(y_true[i]))
        i=i+1

    acc=difs/len(y_true)
    return acc
```

I'm trying to calculate the margin of error of a vector, but I don't know if I'm doing it mathematically right.

Comment: Why would you use random values for confirmation?

Answer (score 0):

> The margin error is calculated by using standard diviation and sample
> size not by comparing the magnitudes of individual higher dimentional
> vectors.

[image]

Above is the formula for calculating the margin of error.

for margin error, I got this definition from here: https://www.formpl.us/blog/margin-of-error

> A margin of error is a statistical measurement that accounts for the
> difference between actual and projected results in a random survey
> sample. In simpler terms, the margin of error allows you to gauge the
> level of unpredictability in data and research outcomes.
>
> For example, let’s say a researcher gives the mean estimate for a
> survey as 50 with a margin of error of ±5. This means that the actual
> mean, when calculated, could be any value from 45–55.

here is a better code to help you find margin error.

```
import numpy as np

# Create a 5d array
array = np.random.rand(2, 4, 8, 6, 2)

# Flatten the array into a 1d array
flt_arr = array.ravel()

# Calculate the mean and standard deviation 
mean = np.mean(flt_arr)
std = np.std(flt_arr)

# Choose a confidence level and find the corresponding z value
#where z is the critical value for the desired confidence level, and standard_error is the standard deviation divided by the square root of sample size.
confidence_level = 0.95 
z = 1.96 

# Calculate sample size
sample_size = np.size(flt_arr)

# Calculate standard error
standard_error = std / np.sqrt(sample_size)

# Calculate margin of error
margin_of_error = z * standard_error


print("Mean:", mean)
print("Standard deviation:", std)
print("Standard error:", standard_error)
print("Margin of error:", margin_of_error)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I guess I didn't explain my question fully. I have one 5-variable vector and one that should be 5-variable vector. But based on what you have told, I think it would be more efficient to calculate the error separately for each variable and take the average instead of actually taking the length of this vector.